# Autolayout Constraint issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I've been trying to learn about autolayouts in xcode 5 by watching some youtube videos. On the videos, they say:

1. switch on autolayout (which I've done)
2. Then while dragging an object around the storyboard you'll see blue guides (which I do).
3. Then, when letting go mouse the mouse, a constraint which look like the letter 'I' appears.

However, this doesn't happen for me - it's like constraints aren't being added?

Am I doing something wrong? Hope this isn't too vague!

Shell

Answer (score 0):

After you place a View inside Interface Builder and blue lines did appear,

- click on the **Resolve auto layout issues button** *(second to last button in the bottom right corner; looks like circle between vertical lines)*
- select the **Add missing constraints** option

The constraints that were "proposed" by by the blue lines should now be automatically added to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 added constraints automatically. 
Xcode 5 only adds constraints if you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

To add constraints in Xcode 5 you need to explicitly lay them out.

You are only one step away...

1. Turn on auto layout.
2. Add you element to the view. You will see the blue guidelines.
3. Add your constraints by holding down CTRL and clicking from the element you added to the one you wish to add a constraint between.

e.g. If you want to add a constraint for the width of the element. CTRL-drag from the elements back to itself.

If you want to add a space constraint to the superview then CTRL-drag from the element to its superview in the direction you want to add the constraint.

If you want to add a space constraint between two elements. CTRL-drag from one element to the other.